# Need Help Optimizing PHP script pulling Site Name of test sites

Tags: php

We have around 20 test sites that have various wordpress projects and I have a working script to pull just the name of the blog and add it to an internal site we use to store a bunch of information.

```
<?php
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$c = file_get_contents("http://test1.company.com");
$d = new DomDocument();
$d->loadHTML($c);
$xp = new domxpath($d);
foreach ($xp->query("//meta[@property='og:site_name']") as $el) {
echo $el->getAttribute("content");
}
?>
```

It works just fine the way I have it set up it is just very slow when I have it pulling info from all 20 sites. I was wondering if theres a way to optimize how its pulling the information?

Comment: Parsing HTML just isn't fast. I you want this to go faster get a server which a lot of horsepower.

Comment: You need to measure how long each line of code takes to execute, to know which ones would really need to be optimized.

Comment: you'll probably find the file_get_contents() call is the slowest bit, unless the html being fetched is massive. there's nothing you can do to speed up f_g_c unless you upgrade your internet pipe, and/or get "closer" to the sites you're scraping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loading the document with `new DomDocument` will be slow. Imagine you're telling someone to memorize a book for you and all you really care about is the title of the page. You're making them go through a lot of work for something you can already get the answer to.

When you receive the contents as a raw string, run a `preg_match` on it to pull the value, should be considerably faster especially since you know it's part of the `og:site_name` meta tag.

I hope this helps!

**Update**

I would also take it a step further and only retrieve the first 1000 characters so you're not pulling in the entire document. Since you're doing a regular expression search on it you can bypass all the XML parsing.

If you need to get more information, then you're probably stuck pulling the entire document.

Here's an example of getting the first 1000 characters:

`file_get_contents('./people.txt', NULL, NULL, 0, 1000);`

The last two arguments are `offset` and `max length`. You want to start at the first character (`0`) and get `1000` bytes/characters only.

Comment: I'm assuming its not possible to offset non-local files?